# Require Opportunity Products on Opportunity in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

The requirement is that the customer wants a way during Opportunity creation to require the Opportunity products being filled in.

Workflow would only help after the save, they want it to evaluate before the save.  Validation would only work on the opportunity.  I'm unsure if a trigger would work or not.

Any ideas?

Comment: I found the answer.  Apparently you can use a validation rule to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to this in case anybody else needs to know how to provide this ability
You can create this as a validation rule after all.  The formula is below:

```
NOT(OR(ISNEW(),HasOpportunityLineItem))
```